# BDD testing a Node.js , Express.js , Socket.io and mongo with mocha

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, mongoose, mocha.js

What is the best method to test a node.js application using express , sokcet.io and mongoose , by using mocha ?

EDIT :
i should mention that i am writing tests with mocha and zombie.js ..
but there are some errors with socket.io i cannot figure out what is the source of it !

such as the following error

```
Cannot call method 'onClose' of null
```

Comment: try searching for "onClose" word in source code.. try to output more when debugging, its really difficult to understand from where that comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about casperjs with yadda.
Its quite flexible and yadda gives option to write your own definitions.